# The left side bar is being pushed to the right

Tags: html, css, layout

I just made my website header and now I'm trying to build the side bar, however instead of sticking to the left, it's being pushed to the right and I don't know why... but I guess it's because of the float elements that I added in the header? I've tried setting the margins to 0, floating it to the left, and nothing works.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

:root {
  --color-primary: #b22222;
}

/* Box */

#box {
  margin: 2% 20%;
}

/* Header */

#header {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.oldenhook_icon {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.header_h1 {
  color: #800000;
  font-family: "Noto Sans Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 22%;
}

.list-item {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Search box */

#searchbox {
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <div id="box">
      <div id="header">
        <i
          ><img
            class="oldenhook_icon"
            src="icons/icon2.png"
            alt="The Oldenhook Icon"
        /></i>
        <div>
          <h1 class="header_h1">[&nbsp;oldenhook&nbsp;]</h1>
          <ul class="flexbox">
            <a href="#" class="list-item">home</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">search</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">global</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">social net</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">invite</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">faq</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-item">logout</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="searchbox">
            
           <label for="email">Email:</label>
           <input name="email" id="email" type="text">
           <p>oifjqoifjq</p>
           <p>ofijqofiqjf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and you just need to remove  `float: right` your sidebar will be on the left or I'm missunderstanding your question

Comment: You should get out of the habit of using floats in general. After 15 years of CSS development there's exactly one use case for them, in my mind, which is for wrapping text around an image. Otherwise, they're more trouble than they're worth.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine just remove `float: right;` from class `flexbox` in css

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `position: absolute;` to class `.flexbox{}`